# error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int *’ and ‘int’)

Tags: c, ip, syntax-error

I am trying to convert a number in IP address using pointers in C.

for example: `IP = 3229305093 192.123.73.5`

and the error i have is:

> error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int *’ and ‘int’)
> bytes[i] = (*ip1 >> (int *)i*8) & 0xFF;

Here is my function:

```
void print_ip(int* ip1) {
unsigned char bytes[4];
int i;

for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
  bytes[i] = (*ip1 >> (int *)i*8) & 0xFF;
}

printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);

}
```

Comment: What is the expected results that you want?

Answer (score 2):

Both operators of bit-shift operator `>>` should be integers. The extra cast should be removed.

Wrong:

```
  bytes[i] = (*ip1 >> (int *)i*8) & 0xFF;
```

Correct:

```
  bytes[i] = (*ip1 >> i*8) & 0xFF;
```